# Calculation of indicial equation using Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

How to calculate the solutions of indicial equation of
$$2xy''-xy'+(1+x)y=0?$$

My working:
After applying the Frobenius method, the lowest power of $x$ in terms of $r$ comes out to be $r-1$ (putting $n=0$), and the corresponding indicial equation turns out to be $2r(r-1)=0$ which gives $r=0$ and $r=1$ as the solutions of the indicial equation.

1. Are the method and the values correct?
2. Also can anyone clarify that the indicial equation is the equation corresponding to the lowest power of $x$ in terms of $r$ (which is $r-1$ in this case) or is it the equation corresponding to the $r$th power of $x$ (if by definition)?

Comment: See my answer for a similar problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460559/solving-using-frobenius-method/3464506#3464506 ; I think you will get your answer from here.